# Get child component state in parent component

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a contact list where you can add contacts to your favorites. Then filter my favorite contacts.

First all contacts have the state `isFavorite: false`, then I click on one contact, click on the star that sets `isFavorite: true`. I close that contact and click on the filter button, to see all my favorite contacts

so in here I add a contact to my favorites:

**ContactName.js**

```
state = {
    isFavorite: false
  }

handleFavorite = () => {
    this.setState({
      isFavorite: !this.state.isFavorite
    })
  }

render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.props.contact.name}
        </li>
        {
          this.state.isOpen ?
            <Contact
              contact={this.props.contact}
              close={this.handleClick}
              favorite={this.handleFavorite}
              isFavorite={this.state.isFavorite}
            />
          : null
        }
      </React.Fragment>

    )
  }
```

**Contact.js**

```
<Favorites
  id={contact.id}
  name={contact.name}
  onClick={this.props.favorite}
  state={this.props.isFavorite}
/>
```

**Favorites.js**
this is just where the favorite component is

```
<span onClick={this.props.onClick}>
  {
    !this.props.state 
    ? <StarBorder className="star"/> 
    : <Star className="star"/>
   }
</span>
```

and here is where I want to be able to get the `isFavorite` state. This is the parent component where the button for filtering the contacts is.

**ContactList.js**

```
<React.Fragment>
  <span
    className="filter-button"
   >Filtera favoriter</span>
   <ul className="contacts">
     {
       this.props.contacts           
.filter(this.handleSearchFilter(this.props.search))
      .map(contact => (
         <ContactName
            key={contact.id}
            contact={contact}
            name={contact.name}
          />
        ))
       }
     </ul>
  </React.Fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in the wrong direction.

In the React, you can pass the data down with props (or by using Context which is no the case here). So if you need a data on the ancestor component, the data should be state/props of that ancestor.

In your case, the `favorite` data should be inside of the `contacts` (that is defined as props of the ContactName), and you should pass it to the `ContactName` just like other props.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <span
    className="filter-button"
   >Filtera favoriter</span>
   <ul className="contacts">
     {
       this.props.contacts           
.filter(this.handleSearchFilter(this.props.search))
      .map((contact, index) => (
         <ContactName
            key={contact.id}
            contact={contact}
            name={contact.name}
            isFavorite={contact.isFavorite}
            handleFavorite={() => this.props.handleFavorite(index))}
          />
        ))
       }
   </ul>
</React.Fragment>
```

and inside your **ContactName.js**

```
render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {this.props.contact.name}
        </li>
        {
          this.state.isOpen ?
            <Contact
              contact={this.props.contact}
              close={this.handleClick}
              favorite={this.props.handleFavorite}
              isFavorite={this.props.isFavorite}
            />
          : null
        }
      </React.Fragment>

    )
  }
```

and `toggleFavorite` function also should be the same place as the `contacts` state is.

Comment: It doesn't work. Now Every contact is added to favorites even though I added one contact. Or did I miss something

Answer (score 0):

In React, parent components should not have access to their children's state. Instead, you need to move your `isFavorite` state up a level to your `ContactList` component and turn it into a list or map instead of a boolean.

**ContactList.js**

```
class ContactList extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // In this example, `favorites` is a map of contact ids.
    // You could also use an array to keep track of the favorites.
    favorites: {},
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className="filter-button">Filter a favorite</span>
        <ul className="contacts">
          {this.props.contacts
            .filter(this.handleSearchFilter(this.props.search))
            .map(contact => (
              <ContactName
                key={contact.id}
                contact={contact}
                isFavorite={!!this.state.favorites[contact.id]}
                name={contact.name}
                handleFavorite={() => this.handleFavorite(contact.id)}
              />
            ))}
        </ul>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }

  handleFavorite = contactId => {
    // Use a callback for state here, since you're depending on the previous state.
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        ...state.favorites,
        [contactId]: !state.favorites[contactId], // Toggle the value for given contact.
      };
    });
  };
}
```

Now the `handleFavorite` and `isFavorite` props can simply be passed down as needed to your child components.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I've managed to get the childs state in the parent. But now everytime I add a new contact to my favorites, it creates new objects - see codebox https://codesandbox.io/embed/charming-bohr-rwd0r

Is there a way to mash all of those new created objects into one object and set that one big objects equal to a new state called favoriteContacts = []?